# programmatically styling elements

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

Hi all I have an element that I would like to apply multiple styles to conditionally

At first, I did this:

```
    <Text
        style={[
          discountCodeState === '' || !isActiveHandler(value)
            ? [
                style.submitText,
                isActiveHandler(value) ? style.submitTextActive : null,
              ]
            : discountCodeState === 'success'
            ? [style.submitText, style.submitTextSuccess]
            : [style.submitText, style.submitTextError],
        ]}
      >
        {submitText}
      </Text>
```

This was working correctly but that's a lot of redundant code so I refactored it to this:

```
   <Text
        style={[
          style.submitText,
          discountCodeState === '' && isActiveHandler(value)
            ? style.submitTextActive :
             discountCodeState === 'success'
            ?  style.submitTextSuccess
            :  style.submitTextError,
        ]}
      >
        {submitText}
      </Text>
```

But for some reason `style.submitText` gets lost somehow I have no idea why??

Thank you

Comment: In your first logic, When `style.submitText` is applied it's only followed by `style.submitTextActive` or `null` However in the second one You're adding `style.submitText` first then doing some logic to apply other styles which i suspect are overriding `style.submitText`

Answer (score 1):

Style fields that are present in `style.submitText` and in the other 3 styles will be overriden by the other 3.
        when you put the same style fileds in a style array the last field will override.

example:

```
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
  style1: {
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    width:'100%',
    height:'50%',
    ...
  },
  style2: {
    backgroundColor:'red',
    width:'50%',
    ...
  },
  style3: {
    backgroundColor:'green',
   ...
  },
});

<View style={[styles.style1, styles.style2, styles.style3]}/>
```

your view's style will have:

```
{
    backgroundColor:'green',
    width:'50%',
    height:'50%',
}
```